# Multi Level Color in Doughnut Chart in ng2-charts

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, ng2-charts

I'm getting started with `Chart.js` and `ng2-Charts` in `Angular`. and now I'm doing Doughnut Charts and wanted to do a **Multi Level Chart** but can not change the color for every level. The Color I chose is only on the first level and not on the others.

here is my **doughnut-chart.component.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartType, ChartOptions } from 'chart.js';
import { MultiDataSet, Label, Color } from 'ng2-charts';

@Component({
  selector: 'doughnut-chart',
  templateUrl: './doughnut-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./doughnut-chart.component.css']
})

export class DoughnutChartComponent {

  doughnutChartLabels: Label[] = ['SPD', 'CDU', 'Grüne', "Linke", "FDP", "AFD", "Andere"];
  doughnutChartData: MultiDataSet = [
    [33, 21, 9, 9, 11, 13, 5 ],
    [35, 20, 10, 10, 15, 15, 10 ],
    [40, 15, 5, 15, 20, 5, 20 ]
  ];

  public doughnutChartColors: Color[] = [
    {
      backgroundColor:
      [
      'red',
      'black',
      'green',
      "purple",
      "yellow",
      "blue",
      "grey"
      ],
      hoverBackgroundColor:
      [
      "lightgrey",
      "grey",
      "lightgrey",
      "grey",
      "lightgrey",
      "grey",
      "lightgrey",
      ],
    }
  ];

  doughnutChartType: ChartType = 'doughnut';

  doughnutChartOption: ChartOptions = {}
    
}
```

Dose someone know what to do ? I found nothing on the Internet about this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of defining the data as a `MultiDataSet`, you can define it as an array of `ChartDataSets` and define the colors on each `dataset` as follows.

```
doughnutChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    {
      label: 'Dataset A',
      data: [33, 21, 9, 9, 11, 13, 5 ],
    }, {
      label: 'Dataset B',
      data: [35, 20, 10, 10, 15, 15, 10 ],
    }, {
      label: 'Dataset C',
      data: [40, 15, 5, 15, 20, 5, 20 ],
    }    
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.doughnutChartData.forEach(ds => {
      ds.backgroundColor = ['red', 'black', 'green', "purple", "yellow", "blue", "grey"];
      ds.hoverBackgroundColor = ["lightgrey", "grey", "lightgrey", "grey","lightgrey", "grey", "lightgrey"];
    });
  }
```

The `HTML` template would have to look as follows:

```
<canvas baseChart
  [chartType]="doughnutChartType"
  [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"    
  [datasets]="doughnutChartData"
  [options]="doughnutChartOption">
</canvas>
```

Please take a look at this [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng2-charts-nested-doughnut?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdoughnut-chart.component.ts) and see how it works.

Comment: thank you that helped me a lot i didn't know that i can use chart datasets in pie/doughnut charts